# Unable to generate a temporary class

Tags: c#, reference, temporary-directory

I recently upgrade my machine to XP 64 bit and also made some code changes to our software and when I'm doing `new XmlSerializer(valueType)`, where `valueType` is a type that is using `DirectoryItem`, I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
>   error CS0012: The type 'XYZ.Blob.DirectoryItem' is defined in an assembly that is not  referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'XYZ.Services.Blob, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I really can't see why it shows this error. The dll is in the src folder and the exact same application is running with no issue on the same machine (the previous version).

If you have any idea how can I find what it gives this error that would be great.

Comment: Why do you have a DLL in a folder that's named "src"?  That's typically a name for a folder that stores source code files, not DLLs.  Your project setup sounds very unusual, tough to help you.

Comment: its nothing related to the src, i add it by accident;the structure is like the standard .net strcutre

Answer (score 3):

Can you verify that you are not [falling in this unfortunate scenario](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/203076/xmlserializer-does-not-work-on-type-with-constrained-generic-method#details)? If this is the case that's a bug that won't be fixed by Microsoft:

You need some type into an assembly A:

```
public interface IInterface {}
```

And a type to be serialized in another assembly:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Number;
    public void Method<T>() where T : IInterface { }
}
```

Now, try to initialize a XmlSerializer

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
```

Comment: with some reason i can't open the link that you sent, can you paste the content?

Comment: Glad you mentioned this FIVE YEAR OLD bug. Just tried the Interface workaround, no problem now.

Comment: I ran into the same error...but the suggested dummy interface doesn't solve my problem. Actually, I get this error only if my dll is embedded in the exe and loaded by AssemblyResolve event. If the dll is not embedded, it's working fine. Only XmlSerializer has this problem with embedded dll, everything else seems to be fine. By the way, I'm using VS 2010 express, .NET 4.0, build Any platform.

Answer (score 1):

Your assembly has been built for x86 platform.

Have a look at your project's properties -> build -> target platform
It is x86 by default. You need to recompile for x64.

Best option is compiling for "any" - in your case.

Comment: you are right, i the assemblies are built for x86 platform, but that by design.i run on a 64 bit machine, but our application need to be built for x86 for the time being.

Comment: i also don't understand why it tells you the it can't find the reference, while the reference is there and the dll is in the output directory

Comment: It cannot find the reference because it is built for x86 so it would not load it - as far as it is concerned it does not exist because x64 does not exist. build it with "Any CPU" option.

Comment: Build everything as x86. It will run as WOW in x64.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like that the solution was fixed once i changed all my implicit conversion to explicit ones.

thanks for the help.